# How do I format a tibble's output as a Github Flavoured Table?

Tags: r, tibble, github-flavored-markdown

```
iris %>%
  pander::pander(split.table = Inf,
                 pandoc.table = T)
```

The output of this is Markdown, but I want the GF Markdown. Can I format it within R?

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the options listed for `?pandoc.table.return`. Additionally you can modify the justification of columns, which are all center by default. Since there are 5 columns here, you could add the argument `justify = "lllll"` or `justify = c("left", "left", "left", "left", "left")` to change that (or to "right").

```r
pander::pander(
  head(iris), 
  style = "rmarkdown"
  )
```

Output:

```
| Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | Petal.Width | Species |
|:------------:|:-----------:|:------------:|:-----------:|:-------:|
|     5.1      |     3.5     |     1.4      |     0.2     | setosa  |
|     4.9      |      3      |     1.4      |     0.2     | setosa  |
|     4.7      |     3.2     |     1.3      |     0.2     | setosa  |
|     4.6      |     3.1     |     1.5      |     0.2     | setosa  |
|      5       |     3.6     |     1.4      |     0.2     | setosa  |
|     5.4      |     3.9     |     1.7      |     0.4     | setosa  |
```

Which renders as:

| Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | Petal.Width | Species |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.1 | 3.5 | 1.4 | 0.2 | setosa |
| 4.9 | 3 | 1.4 | 0.2 | setosa |
| 4.7 | 3.2 | 1.3 | 0.2 | setosa |
| 4.6 | 3.1 | 1.5 | 0.2 | setosa |
| 5 | 3.6 | 1.4 | 0.2 | setosa |
| 5.4 | 3.9 | 1.7 | 0.4 | setosa |

```r
packageVersion("pander")
#> [1] '0.6.5'
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>